# about android aidl object

Tags: android, aidl

I must pass my object with IPC,like this class

```
public class ForIpc {
    JsonObject info = new JSONObject();
    public void add(String key, String value) {
       info.put(key,value);
    } 
}
```

ForIpc can implents  Parcelable,but how to handle JsonObject?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JSON string as the serial representation of the `JSONObject`.

```
    @Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(info.toString());
}
```

and parse it back when read from the Parcel.

```
info = new JSONObject(parcel.readString());
```